# Quality charts ideas

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET page report.
I am looking for a chart which display quality by grade on bar height.

I was wondering if you have any ideas for me as I have searched the web for few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Microsoft Chart Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)
2. [Google Chart Tools (ajax)](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 1):

SSRS rocks, Just have a try with this tutorial :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13725/Getting-started-with-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281302.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Google has a very easy to use Chart API. You can use your ASP.NET page to gather the data and then render the chart using Google's API

Try this: http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/

There are lots of other Javascript and Flash based charting libraries as well:

http://www.highcharts.com/

http://www.fusioncharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

FusionCharts XT is the leading enterprise charting solution.

Check out their gallery - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/

They also provide integration with ASP.NET (C#) - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?guide-for-web-developers/csnet/CS_BasicExample.html

They've provided tutorials on how to plot charts using a database too - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?guide-for-web-developers/csnet/CS_DB.html

They provide HTML5 charts as well as Flash charts.

The chart portfolio contains over 90 charts and widgets, and 550+ maps.